# Using even function properties to integrate

Tags: integration

How can I integrate this:
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\cos x}{e^\frac{1}{x}+1}dx$$

Using this hint $f(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}+ \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$

Comment: Had a spelling mistake. It is supposed to a power.

Comment: Also, does the hint have a typo? Is it not missing a minus sign?

Comment: What have you tried already to solve this? Questions on MSE are generally better received if you include some of your thoughts and work.

Comment: The second fraction should be $$\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$$.  That way the $f(-x)$ disappears

Comment: Fixed all of the typos I think. And the thing is I have no idea how to start. Let alone solve it.

Comment: Hint: Let $f(x)=\frac{\cos x}{e^\frac1x+1}$. Try to write $f(-x)$ in terms of $f(x)$. What do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$ I=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\cos x}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}+1}dx. \tag{1}$$
Under $x\to-x$, one has
$$I=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\cos x}{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}+1}dx=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}\cos x}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}+1}dx.\tag{2}$$
Now adding (1) to (2), one has
$$ 2I=\int_{-1}^1\cos xdx $$
which is easy to handle.

Comment: While this does solve the problem, it doesn't use the hint. Using the hint does lead to the same final integral though, of course.

Comment: @JohnDoe, it is used.

Comment: Awesome. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @nivalen292, you are welcome.

Comment: @xpaul See the other answer - that is how I interpreted that the question wanted OP to use the hint. While you do sort of use it by inverting the sign and adding, the stuff with the function $f(x)$ happens in the background.

Comment: @JohnDoe, essentially they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x) = \frac{\cos x}{e^{\frac{1}{x}} + 1}$, then $$f(-x) = \frac{\cos x}{e^{-\frac{1}{x}} + 1}=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}\cos x}{1+e^{\frac{1}{x}}}.$$ So, $f(x) + f(-x) = \cos x$. Using the hint, we get

$$f(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}+ \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}=\frac{\cos x}{2}+ \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}.$$
The first term is something nice, and the second term *is an odd function*. Can you see how to compute the integral from here?

Comment: Yes I can manage from here on. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! This was a scary looking integral with a surprisingly clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With the identity:
>   $\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{z} \equiv{1 \over \expo{z} + 1} =
> \left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
> \ds{\mrm{H}\pars{-z} + \mrm{sgn}\pars{z}\,\mrm{f}\pars{\verts{z}}} & \mbox{if} &
> \ds{z \not= 0}
> \\[2mm]
> \ds{1 \over 2} & \mbox{if} & \ds{z = 0}
> \end{array}\right.}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,,$
>   
>   where $\ds{\mrm{H}}$ is the *Heaviside Step Function*,

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1}{\cos\pars{x} \over \expo{1/x} + 1}\,\dd x =
\overbrace{\int_{-1}^{0}\cos\pars{x}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{\sin\pars{0} - \sin\pars{-1}}}\ +\
\overbrace{\int_{-1}^{1}{\cos\pars{x}\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{x} \over \expo{1/\verts{x}} + 1}\,\dd x}^{\ds{=\ 0}}\ =\ \bbx{\sin\pars{1}} \approx 0.8415
\end{align}